# Cookies.ttf font cannot be used in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, fonts

I am trying to use this font in my app:
http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Cookies/

But for unknown reasons my app doesn't see it.

I have used the following snippet to output font's name, but the font is not even presented there:

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

What I've done so far:

1. I have included the font into the target.
2. I've added the font into `Info.plist` file.

Can anybody confirm that this font doesn't work for him also?

Comment: Did you add the entire filename and not just "Cookies"?  Also does it happen to be inside of a folder reference (blue folder)?  Finally, confirm that the name of the font matches the filename with the Font Inspector (look for the POSIX name).

Comment: >Did you add the entire filename and not just "Cookies"? Yes. >Also does it happen to be inside of a folder reference (blue folder)? A blue folder? What do you mean? > Finally, confirm that the name of the font matches the filename with the Font Inspector (look for the POSIX name). How do I do that? Is that possible with Font Book?

Comment: I meant to say PostScript name, but yes you can see it in Font Book.  That's the name to look for, not the filename necessarily.  On the blue folder part, I meant in Xcode is the file inside any folder references (blue folders).  If it is you will have to put the entire path to the font in your plist.

Comment: I am sorry, I found the error: I edited `MyAppTests-Info.plist` file instead of `MyApp-Info.plist`... Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add your Cookies.ttf in your project.

[image]

After in your plist file add Cookies.ttf.

[image]

Now click on your Cookies.ttf file and Check mark Target Membership.

[image]

After use the custom font in your apps below code.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.fontName = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cookies" size:22];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //UIFont *fontName = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Impact" size:22];
    [self.lab setFont:fontName];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Your OUTPUT is :

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I found the error: I edited `MyAppTests-Info.plist` file instead of `MyApp-Info.plist`... Thanks for helping!